# Multilevel inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

Suppose a class C inherits from a class B which overrides a virtual function defined in A. C does not override the function. When a pointer of type A* points to an object of type C, will the function call use the overridden version in B?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm wary of discouraging this kind of seemingly simple questions. C++ has plenty of cases where UB might seem to work but actually doesn't, and it doesn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: @Quentin: Yes and no. A better question would be *"It does call it when I tried, but is that behaviour guaranteed?"* As it stands, the question almost looks like a homework assignment to me.

Comment: @ChristianHackl fair enough!

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

Semantically, `C` inherits its implementation from `B` implicitly.
Concretely, the implementation of a virtual function that's called is the most derived available one.

Answer (score 2):

> When a pointer of type A* points to an object of type C, will the function call use the overridden version in B?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function call will use the overridden version in B, unless you implement the virtual function in C. In that case, the function call will be of C.